# Laravel action() helper ignores APP_URL environment variable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my **.env** file, I have the `APP_URL` set like this:

```
APP_URL=https://example.com
```

However, anywhere I use the `action()` helper to generate a URL, the path is created with **http** instead of **https**.

I don't understand why this happens. The site itself runs on SSL. I also tried settings `BASE_URL` environment variable using "https" - no luck.

Shouldn't Laravel respect my base URL?

Laravel version: 5.2

This happens for the `action()` helper, as well as when using HTML & Forms Laravel Collective Package to generate forms (which include `action` property).

Comment: what about `config/app.php`? Mine is `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'http://localhost'),`

Comment: @Thomas Yes, it's set exactly like this.

Comment: then change it to `'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://example.com'),`

Comment: @Thomas Tried it, no change. As long as I have the `APP_URL` in .env, this fallback value is ignored anyway.

Comment: Is the incoming connection secure? Laravel could be unable to detect SSL. Try to put this in the boot method of the AppServiceProvider: URL::forceSchema('https');

Comment: @piscator I did just that 10 minutes ago, and yes - *it works now*. However, still not sure why I even need to do it.

Comment: I think Laravel doesn't automatically force SSL and leaves some freedom to the developer. The helpers asset() / secure_asset() and url() / secure_url() are indications of this. But I don't understand exactly why https in the APP_URL is ignored.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately `action()` is not based on app.url, but in your request root, so if you are browsing https, it should give you an https scheme based url. But can force it to be whatever you need by doing:

```
app('url')->forceRootUrl(env('APP_URL'));
```

I suggest you to do that on a Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Also, in addition to what Antonio suggested in his **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40912975/2890610)**, you can also use the forceSchema() method:

**AppServiceProvider.php**

```
public function boot() {

    if (App::environment('production')) {
        URL::forceSchema('https');
    }
}
```

Notice the code uses Facades, but you could also use the global `app()` helper.

Answer (score 0):

More up to date solution with Laravel 9+ : use the `URL` facade.

```php
URL::forceRootUrl(config('app.url'));

$absoluteLink = URL::action(
    [\App\Http\Controllers\MyController::class, 'getMyRedirect'],
    ['param' => $param],
);
```